# TYPO3 TCA categories and FAL

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-tca

I would like to illustrate the following in the TCA of TYPO3 v9.5.5

- Category 1 (Select selection from dataset, after selection one should be able to select PDFs)

--- FAL 1

--- FAL 2

--- FAL 3

- Category 2

--- FAL 1

--- FAL 2

I find it hard to find an approach. I am relatively new to TYPO3. About "type = inline" does not work, because the SELECT fields should be.
I do not want a ready-made solution, just approaches. Happy with links to documentaries or sources.

Comment: are those categories coming from system categories?

Comment: Don't from system categories.

Comment: so you have an extra table with the name catagory and this table has a relationship to the pdfs?

Comment: Do you need something like that? http://prntscr.com/ncmq1j

Comment: Aristeidis Karavas, that's how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer on my comment what you need is the following:

```
'yourField' => [
   'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:yourExtension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:yourfield',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'nameofpdftables',
            'MM' => 'nameofthe_relation_mm',
        ],
    ],
```

If you created the extension with Extension manager, then the **mm** table should automatically be there. Then you will see the pdfs that belong to this field.

Comment: Without Extension manager. This works with FAL? Are you sure?

Comment: since you didnt create your extension with Extension Builder, is hard to understand what you want exactly. Would you mind posting your code here?